# SSL error when open jupyter notebook in Microsoft Edge

Tags: python, ssl, jupyter-notebook, tls1.2, tls1.3

I'm opening a jupyter notebook in an Ubantu with MobaXterm.
At first , everything worked well and jupyter notebook can be open normally.
Suddenly one day when I open it in Microsoft Edge by typing "jupyter notebook", it gives the following message and the web page gives the error "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH"

```
[W 21:16:49.329 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 9 ('10.21.144.80', 56849): [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:726)
[W 21:16:50.459 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 9 ('10.21.144.80', 56850): [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:726)
[W 21:16:50.555 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 9 ('10.21.144.80', 56851): [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:726)
[W 21:16:50.719 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 9 ('10.21.144.80', 56852): [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:726)
[W 21:16:55.935 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 9 ('10.21.144.80', 56854): [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:726)
```

Try again with https, it gives

```
[W 21:55:56.774 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 9 ('10.21.144.80', 57721): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:726)
[W 21:55:56.777 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 10 ('10.21.144.80', 57722): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:726)
[W 21:55:56.940 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 9 ('10.21.144.80', 57723): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:726)
[W 21:55:56.958 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 10 ('10.21.144.80', 57724): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:726)
[W 21:56:02.134 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 9 ('10.21.144.80', 57727): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:726)
[W 21:56:02.142 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 10 ('10.21.144.80', 57728): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:726)
[W 21:56:02.322 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 9 ('10.21.144.80', 57729): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:726)
[W 21:56:02.323 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 10 ('10.21.144.80', 57730): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:726)
```

But surprsingly it can be open in IE browser with a warning "DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CADLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID"
I also tried Chrome, just the same mistake.
I also tried most solutions I can find, just nothing happened.(;o;)

What's wrong with my computer? Thanks for your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try it on other explorer? like Chrome?

Comment: Tried just now, exactly the same error as edge

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the tls 1.0 and 1.1 protocols have been deprecated. Upgrade your system working with tls 1.2

Comment: I enabled tls 1.0 to 1.3 on my system. Nothing change (; o ;)

Comment: same error with Firefox o iexplore (old browser before Edge)?

Comment: THX!! The solution worked!! I change tls from jupyter's configuration file. That took me a long time to find how to change hhhhh